# Navigation like in the mail app with segues and dynamic cells in a table view?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm currently developing my first iOS app for a college. When you start the app, there is a grouped table view which should represent a menu. This works fine so far, but I'm unable to connect the segues properly. As far as I know I should connect the cell itself with the navigation controller it should lead to. Although every cell should lead to another navigation controller. It's a menu, so that point should be clear. Unfortunately I'm unable to connect a single cell with multiple navigation controllers and when I add multiple prototype cells, I have the problem that every cell should have it's own identifier.

The first screen you see in my app looks basically like the mail app. There are two groups and each cell leads to another navigation controller.

I managed to implement the navigation in some weird way, but get a lot of bugs like "nested push results in corrupted nav bar".

I'm absolutely frustrated right now, I spent a lot of hours on this single problem already and I'm unable to find any solution.

edit:
one of the biggest problems currently is that if I navigate to a point and then head back the the view before, the grouped view is first displayed too close to the top and when the animation is complete the whole view jumps back down where it belongs.

this is how it should look like (and looks like when it jumps back): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34140308/uploads/2016-04-25%2010.28.48.png

this is how it looks like during the animation: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34140308/uploads/2016-04-25%2010.28.48%202.png

edit2: I connected the view controller itself (not the cells) with the respective view controller. Then I call the segues programmatically like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSpeiseplan", sender: self)
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showStudiersaal", sender: self)
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showErzieher", sender: self)
        } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showHausordnung", sender: self)
        } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNews", sender: self)
        }
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showZugewieseneStunden", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

The other major problem right now is that if you press a single cell multiple times before it's loaded, the view gets opened multiple times as well.

Comment: please post some code snippet and or the crash backtrace you are getting in the Xcode console.

Comment: crashes only happen very rarely, but they happen. most of the time it's just a bug with the appearance. and there's no specific code either. I just want every cell to lead to a different navigation controller. Apparently there are a lot of ways to do so but the ways I tried out so far don't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually do segue's from a tableView is by connecting the segue from the viewController rather than the tableviewCells. This way you can call performSegueWithIdentifier in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Eg

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: performSegueWithIdentifier("showSpeiseplan", sender: self)
        case 1: performSegueWithIdentifier("showStudiersaal", sender self)
        case 2: performSegueWithIdentifier("showErzieher", sender self)
        case 3: performSegueWithIdentifier("showHausordnung", sender self)
        case 4: performSegueWithIdentifier("showNews", sender self)
        default: tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    case 1:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: performSegueWithIdentifier("showZugewieseneStunden", sender: self)
        default: tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    default: tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

and in viewWillDisappear:

```
 override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
 }
```

If your cells are editable or dynamic (they change indexPath) then either use cell.tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath to distinguish them, or add a property to you custom cell class (or make one if you haven't) and add a property that you can use to identify the correct segue.

Edit: To fix the tableView Offset jump on animation, create a variable tableViewContentOffset above viewDidLoad, and then in viewDidLoad add:

```
 tableViewContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
```

and in viewWillAppear restore it if it has changed.

```
if tableView.contentOffset != tableViewContentOffset {
    tableView.contentOffset = tableViewContentOffset
}
```

also, maybe just see what happens when you put this in viewWillAppear:

```
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

Comment: That's the way I do it right now, but the problem is, that I have to call "tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)" in addition. The other problem is that if I select a menu point and then navigate back, the grouped table view is first displayed too close to the top. As soon as the animation ends, the whole view jumps down a little bit which is how it should look like.

Comment: Ah I see, although you can just call deselectRow... Before the switch.

Comment: Would you mind posting pictures of the navigation problem and your code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I know, I'm just kind of confused because if I swipe back, this call is required and if I just press the "back" button in the top left, this call is *not* required. And then there's this bug where the whole view jumps a litte bit down. In general it's no problem, but the user might get confused by it. It looks just badly developed in general.

Comment: So just to be clear, you connected your segues from the viewController, not from the cells, and are segueing programmatically in didSelectCellFor...? Have you tried just adding a property to your custom cell class called segueIdentifier, that you load up with your segue id in cellForRow... Then just performSegue with that cells segueIdentifier?

Comment: yes exactly. the navigation itself works, there are just a bunch of problems. I added two screenshots for the problem I just mentioned

Comment: I think the problem is actually the navigation, if Xcode is complaining about your navigation, then you would probably end up seeing some weird bugs

Comment: It's very hard to debug a problem like this without some code to have a look at :/

Comment: Thank you for posting the pictures by the way, that made the ui problem much clearer

Comment: I added some code and a description for the other major problem

Comment: First put deselectRowFor... Before your if statements. And for your multipletap problem set tableView.userInteractionEnabled to false and then set it to true at the end of your prepare for segue code

Comment: Or better yet in viewDidDisappear

Comment: Alright, I managed to solve the problem with double tapping. The other problem (jumping view) is unfortunately still there. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a bit more tricky. It could be a content Offset for the tableView set after viewDidAppear, or a header for the table being set after the segue. Does any of this apply to you?

Comment: I didn't set anything special there. I just added the tableview and implemented the methods to display the data I have. Everything else is done automatically (auto-layout).

Comment: What constraints? I didn't add any, or do you mean constraints that were added automatically? Where can I find them?

Comment: I have to add that the first time I go back to this view that is shown on the screenshot everything works fine, this bug occurs every time after the second time when I go back to it. So let's say it's 'View2' that has this bug and the navigation is like 'View1' -> 'View2' -> 'View3'. It doesn't matter how often I go from 'View1' to 'View2', everything works fine. The problem only occurs when going from 'View3' back to 'View2' and this only happens on the second time going back. This bug isn't only on 'View2' but on every view that uses grouped sections.

Comment: And I just found out that this bug only occurs in portrait orientation and not in landscape.

Comment: Ok, try what I added to my answer and if none of that works I'll have a proper think about why that might happen.

Comment: Looks like it works now, although the offset doesn't seem correct. The view isn't jumping anymore after the animation is done, but the whole tableview is way too close to the top. You can't even see the group-title anymore. Is there a "proper" way to get the "real" offset?

Comment: The viewWillAppear one?

Comment: Actually both, because both have the same result. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukxcl5ni0rqe9xt/2016-04-25%2014.41.04.png?dl=0

Comment: Alright, your solution does *not* work. Apparently during the animation `tableView.contentOffset` is always `CGPointZero`. And during `prepareForSegue` the `contentOffset` is `CGPointZero` as well. I noticed that `viewDidAppear` is called *after* the animation, but the tableview is displayed wrong *during* the animation.

Comment: See my amended edit, if that doesn't work do the exact same thing except with the content inset

Comment: No you need to call it in viewWillAppear, not viewDidAppear

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. This jumping-behavious is still there.

Comment: Weird! Print the tableViews content offset and content inset in viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. Maybe that will shed some light on the situation

Comment: In didLoad and willAppear it's (0.0, 0.0), which displays everything correct. That's when I go from 'View1' to 'View2' (example from before). If I go from 'View2' to 'View3', it's (0.0, -64.0) for willDisappear and then (0.0, 0.0) for didDisappear (which is the last one called out of these 4). If I go back from 'View3' to 'View2', it only calls willAppear and is back to (0.0, 0.0). This little jump is still there and after this jump it is displayed correctly. I guess it has nothing to do with the view itself but with this animation when going from View3 to View2 :x

Comment: How strange! Is anything different from view2 -> 3

Comment: That's why I'm so frustrated, I don't get it to work properly. When I go from View2 to View3 I only notice that the tableview jumps upwards, when going back it jumps back where it should be. Otherwise there's nothing different afaik.

Comment: That is very strange. Throw in some break points at didSelectCell... And prepare for segue, then have a look to see exactly when it jumps up.

Comment: Sorry for the radio silence btw, I was in a meeting.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean there. I'd say there's a problem with preparing the view itself. Like iOS thinks that there's no data/group when heading back to this view (view2) and when it's there and the animation is finished, it suddenly realizes, that there is data. I mean the data is always displayed, but I'm not quite sure about that...

Comment: All I mean is that there must be a point at which the tableView jumps upwards prior to the segue. Try to find that function.

Comment: I'm not really able to find such a point. Although I just found out, that if the view gets loaded again (viewDidLoad()), then the behaviour is the same as if I completely restarted the app.

Comment: Are you calling viewDidLoad programmatically?

Comment: I'm not (except the super.viewDidLoad() when overriding it) and the jump is somewhere between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear of view3

Comment: What are you doing in viewDidLoad for view3? Also am I right in thinking that it is View 2 where the tableView is jumping?

Comment: First of all I'm calling the super method and then I assign two values to two variables. View3 displays just some text, nothing more. And you're right, view2 is where the jumping occurs.

Comment: Maybe set the content inset on view2's tableView in viewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear. I think there is a more annoying underlying problem though

Comment: I tried that already but it doesn't change anything. - That's what I think as well, I just don't get it why this problem even occurs because the code is very simple.

Comment: As a last resort, rebuild the app (if it's simple enough) in a new project, copy and pasting etc. Other than that I'm at a loss! Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: If you do rebuild it, make sure to rebuild view2 by hand, don't copy and paste it obviously.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. This problem might stay unsolved but at least the other one is solved now :)

Comment: No problem at all! If it doesn't change and you would like me to have a look at the project just start a discussion with me and I'll have a crack at debugging it :)